# Uninstall many programs

Tags: windows, uninstall

How to uninstall many programs in Windows?

Right now I browse to `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features` then choose programs one at a time.

Is there any application where I can check a list of programs to uninstall then leave my computer to do them all?

Comment: google is sometimes helpful

Comment: @AK4749 I followed one of the links from your page to see if it those apps were legit and it started downloading random exe's I hadn't asked for

Comment: do people troll in SE now?? that's completely pathetic

Comment: I'm sure it wasn't deliberate but my browser asked me if I wanted to download `cbsidlm-tr1_9-PC_Decrapifier-ORG2-10636481.exe`

Comment: @ColonelPanic One of the links in that article is for a program called PC Decrapifier. You probably clicked it and it started downloading what looks like the installer for that program. I don't see anything wrong with that.

Comment: @AK4749, it doesn't matter that you can find this information on Google. That's kind of irrelevant. It's a legitimate question.

Comment: @dangph yeah, i concede I may have been a bit harsh, especially given how helpful the site has been to me, but let's be honest - first result for "uninstall multiple programs" on a site that has infinitely more exposure than Superuser? cmon.

Comment: @AK4749, I think it's useful to have this question here because we have voting and comments and a reputation system, which are things that eHow don't appear to have. More discussion on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-should-we-deal-with-google-questions

Comment: @dangph thanks for the link, it's an excellent discussion and I'll keep that in mind for next time. I can kind of see the point now, and let's face it, what harm done by an easily answerable question?

Answer (score 2):

Yes Iobit Uninstaller has a **Batch uninstall** component that will accomplish what you desire. It helps you uninstall and remove unwanted programs and folders from your computer fast and easily. Where the built-in and sluggish "Windows Add or Remove Programs" option fails, IObit Uninstaller works as always and picks up the slack. What's better, it is a free Uninstaller without installation.

http://www.iobit.com/advanceduninstaller.html

Answer (score -1):

CCleaner (Tools / Uninstall) - you still have to open the uninstall wizards one by one, but you can complete them in parallel (usually).

http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner

Comment: This has to be a sponsored post/advertisement. I have the latest version of CCleaner and there is no readily visible way to check multiple programs to uninstall. Someone please confirm this and remove this post

Comment: Yeah, ditto. Tools -> Uninstall works the same way as the Windows control panel, you can only uninstall applications one at a time.

Comment: Ok, it looks like I was being too harsh - my sincere apologies. I was not familiar with the site's modus operandi. That said, I'm going to leave my downvote because there are certainly better (and more correct) answers to your question, as evidenced above.